Magento 2.4.7 multiple wysiwyg editor not working
We have create custom admin grid form and use three wysiwyg editor but not working in magento 2.4.7 but working on magento 2.4.6.
please see given below Screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/4c4kUe6MxUSg (in last two editor not working).

My Ui_Component file code given below.
<fieldset name="customfield">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Admin grid edit</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
   
    <field name="intial_message" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Max 60 characters are allowed. Use {{minvalue}} to Display Free Shipping Amount.</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Initial Message</label>
             <dataType>text</dataType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">200</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataScope>intial_message</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
    <field name="in_progress_message" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Max 60 characters are allowed. Use {{subtotal}} to Display Free Shipping Remaining Amount.</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">In Progress Message</label>
             <dataType>text</dataType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">200</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataScope>in_progress_message</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
    <field name="achieved_message" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Max 60 characters are allowed.</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Achieved Message</label>
             <dataType>text</dataType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">200</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataScope>achieved_message</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>

  
    </fieldset>

any idea for the above issue? so please let us know.

Have you found a solution for this?

try set collapsible in true
<item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>


Use separate fieldset for each field to fix the issue in 2.4.7
<fieldset name="customfield">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Admin grid edit</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
    </item>
</argument>   
<field name="intial_message" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Max 60 characters are allowed. Use {{minvalue}} to Display Free Shipping Amount.</item>
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Initial Message</label>
         <dataType>text</dataType>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">200</rule>
        </validation>
        <dataScope>intial_message</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg>
            <settings>
                <rows>5</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>  
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="customfield2">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Admin grid edit</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>
</argument>   
<field name="in_progress_message" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Max 60 characters are allowed. Use {{subtotal}} to Display Free Shipping Remaining Amount.</item>
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">In Progress Message</label>
         <dataType>text</dataType>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">200</rule>
        </validation>
        <dataScope>in_progress_message</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg>
            <settings>
                <rows>5</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>   
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="customfield3">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Admin grid edit</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<field name="achieved_message" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Max 60 characters are allowed.</item>
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Achieved Message</label>
         <dataType>text</dataType>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">200</rule>
        </validation>
        <dataScope>achieved_message</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg>
            <settings>
                <rows>5</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>  
</fieldset>

